# How to deploy "ear" project from Eclipse or JBoss Studio to JBoss or Wildfly app server

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss, wildfly

in my JBoss IDE, I have an instance of JBoss application server I can run. The problem  I have is that I don't know how to deploy an EAR file to a server. The only method I know is over JBoss console or to copy the EAR file into /standalone/deployments folder. Is there some other way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your project to the server, something like this (I'm considering you have Dynamic Web Project or similar):

1) First select your server from the Servers tab

[image: First]

2) Then go to Add and Remove and select your project. So you'll see something like the third print

[image: Second]

3) Then, after you move your project from "Available" to "Configured" you can just Start the server.

[image: Third]

You can also take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgMTHhv54cM) , it's a video about doing what you need. It's not Wildfly, but it's almost the same.

Comment: What If I don't find the project in the "Add and remove" window? Is a right idea to mark a project or ear file as "mark as deployable" (right click on the project)?

Comment: Yes, if you use the "Mark as Deployable" it will try to deploy, even if it doesn't appear in the list. It's not guaranteed that it will deploy without erros though.